# Template deduction for POD and pointer types

Tags: c++, visual-studio, templates, c++17

I've been working on my archiver, which I had to sort of re-implement recently. It's based on [this archiver lib](https://github.com/voidah/archive) I've found, but also I've had to add support for serialize polymorphic object with their type info. I've been trying to solve this with with utilizing template deduction, but It doesn't seem right. I've learned that using deduction adds the generated methods to overload pool, but I haven't found anything about if you can overload with template definitions.

Here's the code snippet I have:

```
class Archive {
    // ... ctor, and others

    // --- 
    template <class T>
    const Archive& operator<<(const T& v) const
    {
        *this & v;
        return *this;
    }

    template <class T>
    Archive& operator>>(T& v)
    {
        *this & v;
        return *this;
    }

    // --- 
    template <class T>
    Archive& operator&(T*& v)
    {
        Serializer::LoadObject(v);
        return *this;
    }

    template <class T>
    const Archive& operator&(const T*& v) const
    {
        Serializer::StoreObject(v);
        return *this;
    }

    template <class T>
    Archive& operator&(T& v)
    {
        v.Serialize(*this);
        return *this;
    }

    template <class T>
    const Archive& operator&(const T& v) const
    {
        ((T&)(v)).Serialize(*this);
        return *this;
    }

    // ... the rest of the implementation, serializers for POD, arrays and STL containers    
};
```

The basic usage of this is

```
struct SomePoco{
    int m_someMember;
    int m_someOtherMember;
    template<class AR> void Srerialize(AR&ar){
        ar & m_someMember & m_someOtherMember;
    }
};
```

which works fine. If I'd use with pointers of objects, It'd look like this - way oversimplified, don't worry about the cleanness, just for the record:

```
class SomeSerializableClass : public Serializable{
public:
    // ... some macros that adds Serializable implementations
    template<class AR> void Srerialize(AR&ar){
        ar & m_someMember & m_someOtherMember;
    }    
private:
    int m_someMember;
    int m_someOtherMember;
}

SomeSerializableClass *obj = new SomeSerializableClass();
Archive ar;
ar << obj;
// ... rest of the stuff
```

in this case I'd like to call `template <class T> const Archive& Archive::operator&(const T*& v) const` insted of `template <class T> const Archive& operator&(const T& v) const`. The deduction comes this way: `template <class T> const Archive& operator&(const T& v) const` where `T = SomeSerializableClass *`

The question is: 
- is there any method to override the behaviour of this deduction with custom deduction rule, or
- is there any method to disable deduction for pointers types, so I could define my own operator functions outside of the class?

**Update:**
I have dug myself through [type_trais](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/type_traits) *suggested below* and I'm quite not understand something with it. With this type of traits, It doesn't really seem to work on Visual Studio 2017.

```
template <class T, class = class std::enable_if<std::is_class<T>>::type>
Archive& operator&(T& v)
{
    v.Serialize(*this);
    return *this;
}

template <class T, class = class std::enable_if<std::is_class<T>>::type>
const Archive& operator&(const T& v) const
{
    const_cast<T&>(v).Serialize(*this);
    return *this;
}
```

I've also consulted with the implementation in VS; by spec `is_object` would be fine for me, because I'm looking for those objects which has their `Serialize` function, whether they're an instance of a class or struct. However, `is_object` is a completely different thing in VS, the closes trait was `is_class`.

Do you guys have any suggestions furthermore?

Comment: For detecting PODs and pointers there are type traits. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/type_traits Are you asking how to implement these yourself?

Comment: Something like that is typically done using `std::enable_if_t`, and shoving it as an extra template parameter, invoking SFINAE to exclude the template from participating in overload resolution for specific types.